# Show and hide div containing google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps

I have a Google map in my page. Google Maps V3. the map is inside a div which can be shown and hidden when a user clicks another div.  The problem is that when the div containing the map is shown, the map seems to be rendered all wrong.

This is not the case when I simply load the map in a visible div, initially.

The code looks like

```
$("#shomap").click(function(){
   $("#map_container").removeClass("my_hidden_element_class");
});
```

I have tried some solutions I found here on stackoverflow, such as resizing the map on the click event, but this did not help.  I have also tried moving the Google maps Initialize() function out of the document ready event, and onto the click event.  This also made no difference.

The map always looks like the screen capture below.

If I resize or zoom my browser window, the map adjusts itself and looks great.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Were you looking at implementing the map as a lightbox or in page? I've provided a small snippet below but can elaborate if required, dependent on which solution you were working towards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the cleanest of methods but with a little more work in to the UI, potentially a loading or progress bar and the following would work quite nicely. Google Maps have always been a little temperamental when it comes to loading them whilst they are display none so the following jQuery ensures the DOM structure is there before bringing in the iFrame.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#shomap').click(function(){
        $('#map-container').show(function(){
            $('#map-container').html('<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2404.0307348438287!2d-1.2097479999999716!3d52.947869999999995!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4879e9fa2e6aaaab%3A0xc99bf92a61f8b4dd!2sWollaton+Hall!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1421599711279" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I am using the GMaps API so, adding an <iframe> dynamically was not the solution exactly- but adding the container element (map-canvas) on click  then calling Initialize() worked marvelously.  Thank you.

Incidentally, to whoever down voted this question, there are several similar threads here on Stack Overflow.  This question and answer set may be very helpful to some other user.  asherstoppard was quite able to offer a solution, given only the information I offered.